# How to get data asp.net session object

Tags: asp.net

I am using asp.net C#;
I create a session this type.

How get data from this session ?

```
 using (envanterEntities envanter = new envanterEntities())
        {

            kullanicilar kull = new kullanicilar();
            if (envanter.kullanicilar.Any(n => n.kullaniciAdi == txtUser.Text && n.parola == txtPass.Text))
            {
                Session["parola"] = envanter.kullanicilar.First(n=>n.kullaniciAdi==txtUser.Text && n.parola==txtPass.Text);// my session
                Response.Redirect("MainPage.aspx?userName=" + txtUser.Text);
                HttpCookie cookie1 = new HttpCookie("bilgi");
                cookie1.Name = "bilgi";
                cookie1.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
                cookie1.Value = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            }
```

Comment: Note that you have a problem on the page. The code after `Response.Redirect` will never be called. Nor would it have any meaning otherwise either, since you don't add the cookie to anywhere

Answer (score 2):

```
var yoursession=(TheTypeThatFirstReturns)Session["parola"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
kullanicilar kull1 = (kullanicilar)Session["parola"];
```